# Weird behavior when printing array in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to print an array however I am not getting the desired output, weird numbers appear after the loop finishes printing the pre-defined array.

Code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>    
int main(){    
    int intArray[11] = {1,2,8,12,-13,-15,20,99,32767,10,31};
    int i=0;        
    for(i=0;i<sizeof(intArray);i++){
        printf("%d\n",intArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
8
12
-13
-15
20
99
32767
10
31
11
1629976468
2674040
2665720
1627423265
1
2665616
-2147417856
1629976534
1629976468
2674040
0
1627423172
1629976532
0
1629110043
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
1629976538
0
1629956432
2674276
0
1627407935
```

Comment: Perhaps read that beginner's C programming guide more carefully...!?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reading and spoon-feeding the documentation for OP.


Comment: Thanks for the example code that actually reproduces your observations. Now you should add some details on the steps you made in order to figure out what's wrong yourself. Have you looked up the documentation of the functions/operators you've used? Have you tried to print out the loop index and the stopping condition?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The breaking condition  in `for` loop is wrong! Which causes an [index-out-of bound problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671703/array-index-out-of-bound-in-c) as `i` exceeds the maximum index value that is `10`  because array length is just `11`. The loop break condition should be < length of array( =**11**) but **not** < size of array.
Value of `sizeof(intArray)` is equals to `11 * sizeof(int)` (= **44**).

To understand it  read:  [`sizeof` Operator](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.5.3.4.html):

> #### 6.5.3.4 The sizeof operator, 1125:
>
> When you apply the `sizeof` operator to an array type, the result is the total number of bytes in the array.

According to this when `sizeof` is applied to the name of a static array identifier (not allocated through `malloc()`/`calloc()`), the result is the size in bytes of the whole array rather then just address. That is equals to size of each elements multiply by the length of array.
In other words: `sizeof(intArray)` = `11 * sizeof(int)`  ( as `intArray` length is 11 ). So *suppose* if `sizeof(int)` is 4-bytes then `sizeof(intArray)` is equals to **44**.

Below a code example and its output will help you to understand further(read comments):

```
int main(){
    int intArray[11] = {1, 2, 8, 12, -13, -15, 20, 99, 32767, 10, 31};
    int i = 0;
 
    printf("sizeof(intArray):  %d\n", 
            sizeof(intArray)                       //1. Total size of array
    ); 
    printf("sizeof(intArray[0]):  %d\n", 
            sizeof(intArray[0])                    //2. Size of one element
    ); 
    printf("length:  %d\n", 
            sizeof(intArray) / sizeof(intArray[0]) //3. Divide Size
    );    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
sizeof(intArray):  44    //1. Total size of array:  11 * 4 = 44
sizeof(intArray[0]):  4  //2. Size of one element:  4
length:  11              //3. Divide Size:          44 / 4 = 11
```

<sub>One can check the working code @[ideone](http://ideone.com/jDrlQv), note: I am assuming size of int is `4`.</sub>

Now notice as `sizeof(intArray)` is `44` that is more then length of array hence the condition is wrong and you have [Undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in the code at runtime. To correct it replace:

```
for(i=0; i < sizeof(intArray); i++)
//           ^--replace-----^
//            wrong condition = 44
```

With:

```
for(i=0; i < sizeof(intArray) / sizeof(intArray[0]); i++)
          // ^------------------------------------^
          // condition Corrected = 11
```

To calculate length of array,  I simply divided total size of array by the size of one element and code is:

```
sizeof(intArray) / sizeof(intArray[0])   // 44 / 4 = 11
     ^                 ^
total size of       size of first element
array
```

Comment: Thanks, could you please explain why it should be done like that? `sizeof(intArray)/sizeof(intArray)`

Comment: That condition is still incorrect, the expression will give `1` as numerator and denominator are same!

Comment: You're again making the same *assertion* without any reasoning?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Questioning how the code in question would lead to a buffer overflow doesn't imply that I downvoted you.

Comment: Essentially, this method "normalizes" to determine the number of elements associated with a variable.  In more complicated examples, you might have an array of structures divided by the size of one structure to get the number of structures in the array.

Comment: Unfortunately this method is only available in edge cases, i.e. for arrays that have not (yet) decayed to a pointer. +1 if you add a paragraph on the general case, if you make your answer more concise and if you improve your english.

Answer (score 4):

`sizeof` gives you the size of the array *in bytes*, not elements. To get the number of elements, divide by the size of only one element:

```
for(i = 0; i < (sizeof intArray / sizeof intArray[0]); i++)
{
    printf("%d\n", intArray[i]);
}
```

It's worth noting that this only works for array types, it doesn't work when you have allocated a block of memory using `malloc`.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change `sizeof(intArray)` to

```
sizeof(intArray)/sizeof(int)
```

This will give the number of the array elements.

Comment: thanks, but why should we define sizeof(int)? how is it different from `sizeof(intArray)/sizeof(intArray)`

Comment: @DeepakTivari Because `sizeof` an array name gives the size of the entire array in bytes. `sizeof(intArray)/sizeof(intArray)` is always `1`.

Comment: @DeepakTivari: You're dividing the size of the entire array by the size of only one element, this gives you the number of elements in the array. This answer differs from the others in that `sizeof(int)` is hardcoded. If you were to change the type of `intArray` to `long` for example, you would need to ensure you updated this condition. The other answers do not have this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Update

```
for(i=0;i<sizeof(intArray);i++)
```

to

```
for(i=0;i<sizeof(intArray)/sizeof(intArray[0]);i++)
```

`sizeof(intArray)` gives total size of array in bytes not number of elements in the array.

Answer (score 2):

You have declared `intArray` as an array of 11 `int`s. Each `int` occupies a certain number of bytes in memory (typically four). So the size of the whole `intArray` is 11 * 4 = 44 bytes.

When you say `i < sizeof(intArray)`, you are therefore saying `i < 44`. But your array has only 11 elements, not 44! So your loop will continue past the array bounds. It will continue to read four-byte chunks and interpret them as integers, and print out the garbage values.

That is why all the answers are saying that you need to have your loop condition be

```
i < sizeof(intArray) / sizeof (intArray[0])
```

You need to divide the size of the entire array by the size of a single element to get the number of elements in the array. Since you already know the number of elements, you could keep it simpler and just say

```
i < 11
```

but for more general cases where you might not know the size of the array, you need to use the other suggested loop condition.