# Loop does not set value correctly

Tags: c++, c, arduino

Why does the loop below not set the `pinMode` to `OUTPUT` for the pins in the array `pins[]`?

```
int pins[21];

void setup() {

    int pins[] = {13,
              3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12,
              14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23};

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(pins); i++) {
        pinMode(pins[i], OUTPUT);
    }

}
```

To get it to work, I have to set them manually:

```
pinMode(3, OUTPUT);    
pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
// ...
```

Comment: If pinMode takes an index and not a reference, then you should give it i and not pins[i] inside the loop. Instead you are just setting the indexes that happen to be values inside the array...

Comment: This could be something on the Arduino that I'm not familiar with, but you seem to be setting `pinValues[i] = LOW`, but setting the pin mode for values passed in the `pins` array.  Do you mean to set `pinValues[pins[i]] = LOW`?

Comment: @ZacHowland I meant to store the `LOW` value in the array `pinValues[]`. However using `sizeof(pins)/sizeof(pins[1])` for the loop definition does not seem to set `pinMode()` to `OUTPUT`

Comment: Read [Weird behavior when printing array in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18009725/weird-behavior-when-printing-array-in-c?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong breaking condition causes Undefined behaviour due to n index-out-of bound problem :

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(pins); i++)
                    ^-----------^
```

should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(pins)/sizeof(pins[0]); i++)
                    ^---------------------------^
```

**Note:** When you apply the sizeof operator to an array type, the result is the total number of bytes in the array.

To understand formula read: [Weird behavior when printing array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18009725/weird-behavior-when-printing-array-in-c/18009736#18009736)

Answer (score 1):

Change `sizeof(pins)` to `sizeof pins  / sizeof *pins`.

`sizeof` yields the size of the array in bytes and not the number of elements of the array.

Comment: @Veltas `sizeof *pins` is `sizeof (int)` here. Using the object name has the advantage you don't need to change the type in the `sizeof` operand if you change the type of array.

Comment: Oh God I read that as sizeof pins*, not sizeof *pins. Don't worry!

Answer (score 0):

For starters, `sizeof(pins)` will be `sizeof(int)` times the number of entries in `pins`. Accessing values outside the range causes undefined behavior. You probably meant to use

```
sizeof(pins)/sizeof(pins[0])
```

or in C++ just `size(pins)` with a suitable function template like

```
template <typename T, std::size_t Size>
constexpr std::size_t size(T(&)[Size]) { return Size; }
```

Why the functions don't work can't be seen from the code snippet you provided as the code doesn't include the definition of the functions (or macros) `pinMode()`.

Comment: Why did you choose to use index `1` rather than `0` in `izeof(pins)/sizeof(pins[1])`?

Comment: @Nyxynyx: it is a typo and I shall correct it. May be an interesting research to find out if it matters: since it is a non-evaluated context any index might do but `0` certainly works (as an array needs to have at least one element).

Answer (score 0):

Although you *can* use `sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])` or a template to compute the size of the array (or, equivalently, use it to find the end of the array), if you're using a reasonably current compiler, it already knows how to handle the job correctly on its own:

```
for (auto i : pins)
    pinMode(i, OUTPUT);
```

At least in my opinion, this seems like the simplest of the three.