# Array is converted to a pointer when sizeof expression is used?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, gcc, sizeof

I have the following source :

```
/*file a2ptr.c */ 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>
typedef struct m_St m_St;
struct m_St
{
    size_t idx;
    size_t m_data[8];
}*x;

size_t GetSize(m_St *s)
{
    s->idx=1;
    return (sizeof((s->idx ? x : s)->m_data));
}
int main(void)
{
    m_St s = { 0 };
    printf("GetSize() returns: %zu\n", GetSize(&s));
    return 0;
}
```

On a 32-bit Linux using GCC 4.8.1, this code produces the following output :

```
$ gcc -Wall -Werror a2ptr.c  
$ ./a.out  
GetSize() returns: 32
```

My question :
Is `(s->idx ? x : s)->m_data` a valid expression in C ?
Why GetSize() returns the size of the whole array, (in bytes) and not the size of the pointer to its first element(e.g., `sizeof(size_t)`) ?

Comment: **`6.5.3.4 The sizeof operator, 1125:`**
`When you apply the sizeof operator to an array type, the result is the total number of bytes in the array.` And `sizeof` is a compilation time operator.

Comment: Common sense (or the one cent question): if it was, how would you determine the size of the array? It would be practically pointless.

Comment: From the [ISO C99 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):
**§6.5.3.4** The sizeof operator
88) When applied to a parameter declared to have array or function type, the sizeof operator yields the
size of the adjusted (pointer) type.  
Does this quote applies to my example?  
Any point where did I miss?

Comment: @boleto The "parameter" word. That clause is for function arguments. An array automatically decays into a pointer when passed to a function, but not when it's the immediate argument of the `sizeof` operator. See my updated answer.

Comment: @boleto: A parameter defined with an array type `void func(int array[]);` is "adjusted" at compile time; it really is a pointer: `void func(int *array);`. That's why `sizeof array` yields the size of the pointer. The "decay", or implicit conversion, of an array expression to a pointer is a separate language rule.

Comment: You don't need any of that ternary expression nonsense. Just 'return sizeof m_St.m_data'. The array is converted to a pointer by being passed as a parameter, not by the sizeof operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is `(s->idx ? x : s)->m_data` a valid expression in C ?

Yes.

> Why `GetSize()` returns the size of the whole array, (in bytes) and not the size of the pointer to its first element(e.g., `sizeof(size_t))`?

Read:

> **[`6.5.3.4 The sizeof operator, 1125:`](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.5.3.4.html)**
>
> When you apply the sizeof operator to an array type, the result is the total number of bytes in the array.

According to this when  `sizeof` is applied to the name of a static array identifier (*not* allocated through malloc), the result is the size in bytes of the whole array rather then just address. This is one of the [few exceptions to the rule that the name of an array is converted/decay to a pointer to the first element of the array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752978/exception-to-array-not-decaying-into-a-pointer/17753057#17753057), and it is possible just because the actual array size is fixed and known at compile time, when `sizeof` operator evaluates. So 'array name' not converted into pointer.

To find **length of array** read: [Weird behavior when printing array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18009725/weird-behavior-when-printing-array-in-c/18009736#18009736)

Read also:

> **1118**
>   The `sizeof` operator shall *not* be applied to *an expression that has function type* or an incomplete type, to the parenthesized
>   name of such a type, or to an expression that designates a bit-field
>   member.
>
> **1119**
>   The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand, which may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a
>   type.

Comment: "And sizeof is a compilation time operator." - in this case, yes. Don't forget C99 VLAs, which require it to be a run-time operation.

Comment: @H2CO3 I don't know that, give link. Should I write in C **?**

Comment: (Should write in C - what should you write in C? I don't understand.) It's in the same standard paper you are quoting :)

Comment: 6.5.3.4/2 If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an integer constant.

Comment: @YuHao, H2co3: got `1122 If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated;`

Comment: @H2CO3 And as I know C99 supports VLA so it runtime operator in C99. Am I correct **?**

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan  In C99, `sizeof` is still compile time operator when the operand isn't a VLA.

Comment: @YuHao this is very interesting to know. clear to me now. Thanks!

Comment: @Grijesh Chauhan I think that no conversion on non-lvalue array is done in my example, and sizeof operator computes the size of the whole array, but just wanted to be sure.

Comment: @boleto yes **no** conversion  that is what it returns 32 but not sizeof pointer in your system.

Comment: What specific document are the quotes in this answer from? I do not believe the text “When you apply the sizeof operator” appears in the 1999 or 2011 C standard.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I quoted from  [this: Link](http://c0x.coding-guidelines.com/6.5.3.4.html) I read they explained very nicely, I quoted it in my many answer I got good votes. One I quoted from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w557fh7%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Please do not give quotes that could be mistaken for quotes from the C standard without making it clear that they are not.

Comment: "when sizeof is applied to the name of a static array identifier (not allocated through malloc)" Well, what you get from malloc is a pointer. You don't have an "array". So it's enough to just say "when sizeof is applied to an array".

Comment: @newacct yes, that is not pointer but some new students confuses that why I written like this.

Answer (score 2):

> Array is converted to a pointer when sizeof expression is used?

No.

---

Now seeing your question in comments:

> From the ISO C99 Standard: §6.5.3.4 The sizeof operator 88) When applied to a parameter
>   declared to have array or function type, the sizeof operator yields the size of the adjusted
>   (pointer) type. Does this quote applies to my example? Any point where did I miss?

You missed the word `parameter`. This is basically just another way to say that one can't really pass arrays to a function, only pointers, because arrays always decay into pointers when passed to a function. The clause you are citing concerns the following case:

```
void foo(char arr[1000])
{
    // will print sizeof(char *), because in a function argument context,
    // (and ONLY there), T array[N] is the same as T *arrray
    printf("%zu\n", sizeof(arr));
}
```

Now if your array is..., well, a **real array,** and not a disguised pointer, then it does **not** decay to a pointer if it is the argument of the `sizeof` operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
size_t m_data[8];
return sizeof(m_data);   // <-- in this case same as return (sizeof(size_t) * 8);
```

so if you want to return the count of elements, you should do:

```
size_t m_data[8];
return ( sizeof(m_data) / sizeof(size_t) );
```

*"Array is converted to a pointer when sizeof expression is used?"* **No**. Your confusion is probably based on something, which is called *array decaying*, when an array is converted (*decayed*) into a pointer and the ability of retrieving the length of the array using `sizeof` is lost:

```
size_t getSize(size_t* myDecayedArray) {
    return sizeof(myDecayedArray);     // <-- same as return ( sizeof(size_t*) );
}
...
size_t m_data[8];
return getSize(m_data);                       // <-- array decayed into pointer
```

see [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/1168156)

Answer (score -1):

`sizeof` is computed at compile time - not run time.

Comment: Except when it is computed at run-time.

Comment: - See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225776/why-does-sizeofx-not-increment-x

Comment: What @H2CO3 means is the exception of variable length arrays.