# Trying to get an array.length to work in for loop

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

Can someone help me figure out why this is not working.

```
int main() {
int A[100];

    for(int i=0; i<A.length; i++)
    {

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is my error

`[Error] request for member 'length' in 'A', which is of non-class type 'int [100]'`

Comment: `length` is a Java thing - you want `sizeof`

Comment: Arrays don't have members in C++.

Comment: @sje397 `sizeof` won't give the number of elements in the array though.

Comment: Use `std::array` instead of a C-style array.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c

Comment: Correct is as `for(int i=0; i< sizeof(A) / sizeof(A[0]); i++)`, Read  [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18009725/weird-behavior-when-printing-array-in-c/18009736#18009736)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such thing like `length` attribute for C style arrays. Consider using [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) and it's [`size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/size) member, or `sizeof(A)/sizeof(int)`, if you insists on C style arrays.

Comment: The requirement for the assignment specifically states not to use vectors so I am stuck doing it this way.

Comment: It's an array, not a vector ; )

Comment: I know I was just stating because you said if you insist on C style arrays. This worked btw thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Plain arrays do not have any members. If you need to know their length, you either have to keep track of it, or you can write a simple function template to get it:

```
template<class T, size_t N>
constexpr size_t size(const T (&)[N]) { return N; }
```

then

```
int A[100];
....
for(int i=0; i < size(A); i++) { ... }
```

It would be far easier to use an `std::array<int, 100>`. This has a size method.